# Micro CAP Error: Internal time step too small in transient analysis

Tags: analog, simulation, vco

i try make simple VCO in Micro-cap 12. But when i but when i try to run transient analysis and i get an error.
X1 and X2 is a mcp6001 and Q1 is a BC548B(from standard library)
[image: sheme]
[image: Transient analysis window]
UPD:
after set `Options->Global Settings` and change `CSHUNT` to 1p
simulation stay work for a little. TNX for @SteKulov.

New error: Matrix is singular.
[image: new error]

Comment: sheme from [link](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/projects/diy-synth-series-vco/)

Comment: What program are you using?

Comment: @VoltageSpike micro-cap 12

Comment: Please edit your question and include the information

Comment: What if you try going to `Options->Global Settings` and change `CSHUNT` to `1p`.  Does that help in any way?

Comment: @SteKulov yes, but now its a new error: Matrix is singular,but the simulation works a little.

Comment: You might need a leakage resistor across C1?  Try `100meg` first and play around with the values.

Comment: It did not help. I replaced the op with an LM358 and the circuit worked.

Comment: MCP6001 SPICE model is known to have stability problems.  Hard to work with.